# Bulk rename txt files with different parts using Python

Tags: python, rename

I have a list of files that I wish to rename to.

Receipt ABC-001 623572349-1.txt --> Receipt ABC-001A.txt

Receipt ABC-001 623572349-2.txt --> Receipt ABC-001B.txt

However, even at the first step, everytime  I get the following error "Cannot create a file when that file already exists:". What would be the best option to achieve the above outcome where files ending with 1 will become A; ending with 5.txt will become E.txt, and soforth?

Below is the code I have used:

```
import os, fnmatch

#Set directory of locataion; include double slash for each subfolder.
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Mr.Slowbro\\Desktop\\TBU\\"


#Set file extension accordingly
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.txt')

for file_name in files_to_rename:
    file_name_new = file_name[-5:5]    
    os.rename(file_path + file_name, file_path + file_name_new)
```

Comment: You must have run the code once already, that's probably why Python complains that the file already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out. Using the ord() function returns the Unicode point of a character. So 'a' would be 97, 'b' would be 98, etc. Likewise, chr() returns the character of that Unicode point. So, I think the code below will help you with your issue.

````
#Set directory of locataion; include double slash for each subfolder.
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Mr.Slowbro\\Desktop\\TBU\\"


#Set file extension accordingly
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.txt')

for file_name in files_to_rename:
    number = chr(int(file_name[-5]) - 1 + ord('A'))
    file_name_new = 'Receipt ABC-001' + number + '.txt'
    os.rename(file_name, file_name_new)```
````

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! I am still very new to Python. Could you please recommend ways/resources to take to improve my knowledge on this subject? I am learning a lot from other people's codes here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Automate the Boring Stuff with Python by Al Sweigart is a fantastic book to learn Python with. Also, if this answer helped you, would you mind marking it as the answer? Thanks!